# Automatic form fill value from previous input with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, autofill

I need for a duplicated form to be autofilled since it's being displayed on two different pages, so the user doesn't need to fill it twice. The form in question is a delivery fee one, where the user fills in their zip-code and the fee is calculated.

The second form suggests the autofill from the previous one, I'd just like for it to be automatically filled and selected.

Data from the first form:
[first form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbJUB.png)

```html
<input type="tel" name="PostalCode" id="PostalCode" maxlength="9" size="9" data-name="CEP" placeholder="Calcule seu frete" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
```

Which should already be populated and selected on the following form
[second form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkUMm.png)

```html
<input data-param-id="PostalCode" id="PostalCode" data-mask-postalcode="" maxlength="9" type="text" value="11040-221">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Also read our [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and edit your question to improve it and  [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: Did u saw my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

ID need to unique, take care of it.

You can use val() to get value from the last input and use val() again to put it in first.

You can use focus() to select the input.

Tell me if i dont understand well your problem.

```js
/*$('#PostalCode[data-name=CEP]').bind("change keyup input",function() { 
    let currentValCEP = $(this).val();
    $('#PostalCodeNext[data-param-id=PostalCode]').val(currentValCEP);
});*/

/*$('#first[data-name=CEP]').bind("click button",function() { 
    let currentValCEP = $('#first[data-name=CEP]').prevAll('#PostalCode').val();
    $('#PostalCodeNext[data-param-id=PostalCode]').val(currentValCEP);
});*/


let currentValMask = $('#PostalCodeNext').val();
$('#PostalCode').val(currentValMask).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" name="PostalCode" id="PostalCode" maxlength="9" size="9" data-name="CEP" placeholder="Calcule seu frete" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
<br><br>
<input data-param-id="PostalCode" id="PostalCodeNext" data-mask-postalcode="" maxlength="9" type="text" value="11040-221">
```